# How Do I Pause and Resume a For Loop?

Tags: android, multithreading, loops, wait, postdelayed

I'm a noob to Android and I am trying to cycle text from an arrayList of strings and display them in an textswitcher. I want the text to change every two seconds.  i used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13680281/text-for-marquee-dynamically) SO question as my guide and have no problem switching the text with a button.  However, when I try to cycle the text with a for loop with a 2 second delay it only shows the first text from the arrayList.  How can I make the loop continuously execute with a pause?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

My Code;

```
private void updateCounter()
{   

    try{
    for (int i=0; i< CoinShowReader.tickercontent.size(); i++){                             

        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
             public void run() { 
                m_switcher.setText((CoinShowReader.tickercontent.get(CoinShowReader.m_counter)));               
                CoinShowReader.m_counter++;
             } 
        }, 2000);

        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

remove the loop, you don't need it,  just schedule anther runnable inside the handler like this:

```
void updateTextView(){
        m_switcher.setText((CoinShowReader.tickercontent.get(CoinShowReader.m_counter)));               
        CoinShowReader.m_counter++;

            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                             public void run() { 
                               updateTextView(); 
        } } ,2000);  }
    }
```

that way every call to `updateTextView()` schedule the next call and so on ...

**Note:**  **don't forget to insert trigger to stop that behavior because it's infinity**