# How to Scroll listview continuesly like Marquee

Tags: android, xml

I want scroll the list view continuously like Marquee effect, for that what I need to add for list view.

Comment: be more clear with your question..

Comment: I have one listview, I want that list view to be keep scrolling automatically @Prag's シ

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions here should __show research effort or attempts__. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Please take a __[tour]__.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Refer to this  [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324258/endless-scroll-list-view) or you can use some adapter [EndlessAdapter](https://github.com/JafarKhQ/EndlessListView) or [this one](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless).

*MarqueeLayout.java*

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class MarqueeLayout extends FrameLayout {
    private Animation animation;
    public MarqueeLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        animation = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, +1f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f
        );
        animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
    }
    public void setDuration(int durationMillis) {
        animation.setDuration(durationMillis);
    }   
    public void startAnimation() {
        startAnimation(animation);
    }
}
```

and *MarqueeLayoutActivity.java*

```
import android.app.Activity;
public class MarqueeLayoutActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /*List view code here*/
        MarqueeLayout marqueeLayout = new MarqueeLayout(this);
        marqueeLayout.setDuration(10000);
        marqueeLayout.addView(listView);
        marqueeLayout.startAnimation();
        setContentView(marqueeLayout);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank u SagarP ur post is for state change of list by user, But i want the list to be keeps scrolling automatically, Just like marquee.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525760/how-to-add-marquee-effect-to-listview) answer your question

Comment: I had gonn through that post, but that is for single textview not for entire listview to be scrolling automatically.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: one way to do it may be by using some animations or you can run a thread which will use listview method called `smoothScrollToPosition()`and then set the position to first/last position

Comment: thanks, smoothScrollToPosition() is this a built in function in listview or what?

Comment: I'll try this above method and let u know SagarP, Thanks for help.

Comment: @Qantas 94 Heavy i have now posted some code. is it better now? vote-up if so.